# Restrict time based on date in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a datetime picker control (Datetimepicker for Bootstrap 3 * version : 4.15.35) . If the start date is today, and if the user selects start time as expired time, i would like to restrict it. User should not be able to select expired time. I mean, if the current time is 9 A.M, then user should not be able to select any time before 9 A.M. However, if the start date is tomorrow, then user can select anytime.

User should be able to select any date time greater than current datetime. My current code is as below:

**Index.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label">Start date:<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="startDatepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-model="defaultStartDate" name="startDate">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label">End date:<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="endDatepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-model="defaultEndDate" name="endDate">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--/col-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label">Start Time:<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="startTimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="00:00 AM/PM" ng-model="defaultStartTime" name="startTime">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label">End Time:<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="endTimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="00:00 AM/PM" ng-model="defaultEndTime" name="endTime">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**In controller.js**

```
 var setDefaultDate = new Date();
    $scope.defaultStartDate = moment(setDefaultDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    $scope.defaultEndDate = moment(setDefaultDate).add(1, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    $scope.defaultStartTime = moment(setDefaultDate).format("hh:mm a");
    $scope.defaultEndTime = moment(setDefaultDate).format("hh:mm a");
    jQuery('#startDatepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        defaultDate: new Date()
    });
    jQuery('#endDatepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false
    });
    jQuery('#startDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate($scope.defaultStartDate);
    jQuery('#endDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate($scope.defaultEndDate);

    jQuery("#startDatepicker").on("dp.change", function(e) {        
        jQuery('#startDatepicker').focus();        
        jQuery('#endDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    jQuery("#endDatepicker").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        jQuery('#endDatepicker').focus();
        jQuery('#startDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
    jQuery('#startTimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });
    jQuery('#endTimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });
```

How to set the validation?
Thanks

Comment: You should have used angular-ui-bootstrap which defines directive for the datepicker, and may have defined validation rules

Comment: Hi. Is there no other way? I cannot change the controls. Is there anyway which can be achieved using jquery to show alert message, in such a scenario